# Can't get combobox selected value

Tags: c#, combobox, valuemember

Here is my code -

```
combo.DisplayMember = "Caption";
combo.ValueMember = "PortName";
combo.Items.Add(new { PortName = "port", Caption = "caption"  });

//Null reference exception here-
String PortName = combo.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

What did I miss?

> UPDATE-
>
> ```
> //the following line has solved my problem-
> dynamic item = cmbPortNo.SelectedItem;
> string PortName = item.PortName;
> ```

Comment: do you have datasource ?

Comment: 1. in what **event** did you get selected value 2. is displaying well or not?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just missing `combo.SelectedIndex = 0;` line

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the DataSource property:

```
List<CaptionPortCollection> list = new List<CaptionPortCollection>();
list.Add(new CaptionPortCollection() { Caption = "HTTP", Port = 80} );
list.Add(new CaptionPortCollection() { Caption = "HTTPS", Port = 443} );
...

combo.DisplayMember = "Caption";
combo.ValueMember = "Port";
combo.DataSource = list;
```